# Firebase iOS: Download image for TableView - Best Practice

Tags: ios, firebase-storage

I followed the Firebase tutorial by Ray Wenderlich ([Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2)) and adopted his way of initializing the object (in my case of type "Location") with the snapshot from the observe-method:

**class Location:**

```
init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    identifier = snapshot.key
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
    type = snapshotValue["type"] as! String
    name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
    address = snapshotValue["address"] as! String
    latitude = Double(snapshotValue["latitude"] as! String)!
    longitude = Double(snapshotValue["longitude"] as! String)!
    avatarPath = snapshotValue["avatarPath"] as! String

    ref = snapshot.ref
}
```

**LocationsViewController:**

```
databaseHandle = locationsRef?.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        var newLocations:[Location] = []

        for loc in snapshot.children {
            let location = Location(snapshot: loc as! FIRDataSnapshot)

            newLocations.append(location)
        }

        self.locations = newLocations
        self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

This really works like a charm, but now I'm trying to load the image stored under the storage reference "avatarPath".
My attempt worked but the images take a ling time to load. Is there a better way/place to load these images?

**My attempt 1:**

```
databaseHandle = locationsRef?.queryOrdered(byChild: "name").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        var newLocations:[Location] = []

        for loc in snapshot.children {
            let location = Location(snapshot: loc as! FIRDataSnapshot)

            newLocations.append(location)
        }

        self.locations = newLocations
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        //Load images       
        for loc in self.locations {
            let imagesStorageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child(loc.avatarPath)
            imagesStorageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    loc.avatarImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }
})
```

**My 2nd Attempt (inside Location class):**

```
init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    identifier = snapshot.key
    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
    type = snapshotValue["type"] as! String
    name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
    address = snapshotValue["address"] as! String
    latitude = Double(snapshotValue["latitude"] as! String)!
    longitude = Double(snapshotValue["longitude"] as! String)!
    avatarPath = snapshotValue["avatarPath"] as! String

    ref = snapshot.ref

    super.init()
    downloadImage()
}

func downloadImage() {
    let imagesStorageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child(self.avatarPath)
    imagesStorageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.avatarImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
        }
    })
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Nico

Comment: Why can't you use third party libraries like SDWebImage or AfnetworkingImageDownloader. These really works well in cache and displaying images

Comment: In your first case is clear why it takes too long. you are downloading one by one with no asynchronous task manager and you are reloading the tableView everytime an image is downloaded. In the second time its more or less the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way you can accomplish that is to load asynchronous inside the loading of the cell function. I mean:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   let imagesStorageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child(self.locations[indexPath.row].avatarPath)
        imagesStorageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                locations[indexPath.row].avatarImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
tableView.reloadRows(at indexPaths: [indexPath], with animation: .none)
            }
        })
    }
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly!

Comment: FYI: there's no need to wrap Firebase Storage upload or download methods in a dispatch queue: we'll perform the network requests in the background, and (by default) raise the callbacks on the main thread (so you can update UI).

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcDonald for the info

Answer (score 1):

In first attempt try changing your code as:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
       for loc in self.locations {
            let imagesStorageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child(loc.avatarPath)
            imagesStorageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1*1024*1024, completion: { (data, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    loc.avatarImage = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! :)